# RTCMultiConnection exception on connection.addStream()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, screensharing, rtcmulticonnection

I'm trying to switch source - screen to webcam (LIVE). I've started from function `addStream()` and after executing it I'm getting this error:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': At least one of audio and video must be requested(…) Object {audio: false, video: false}
```

Here is the code:

```
       function switchToWebcam() {

            connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
                OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
                OfferToReceiveVideo: true
            };

            connection.addStream({
                video: true,
                audio: true
            });
        }
```

Maybe there are other ways to switch source. Just can't find an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to add **audio+video** stream in a screensharing session:

```
connection.session.audio = true;
connection.session.video = true;

connection.addStream({
    audio: true, // because session.audio==true, now it works
    video: true, // because session.video==true, now it works
    oneway: true
});
```

You can try this **audio+screen** demo on Canary. This demo has **"Add Video"** button as well.

- https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Audio+ScreenSharing.html

Comment: It works, thanks. Do I need to remove screen stream before creating this new? I'm just trying to make it work in "Scalable Screenshare Broadcast" example

Comment: Scalable-broadcast demo doesn't supports multi-stream features. So you can not add new streams. You can either share screen or audio+screen or audio+video where single MediaStream is shared/relayed.